# What does this sequence converge to? $a_n = \ln(n+1) - \ln(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

So wolfram has that this limit is 0:

[image]

so I think I made a mistake:

$$a_n = \ln(n+1) - \ln(n)$$

$$a_n = \frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}$$

using this theorem:

[image]

and L'Hospital rule:

$$a_n = \frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}$$

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} = \frac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln(x)}$$

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} = \frac{\frac{1}{x+1}}{{\frac{1}{x}}}$$

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} = \frac{(x)}{(x+1)}$$

L'Hospital again:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You just wrongly used the logarithm law. $ln(x)-ln(y)=ln(x/y) \neq ln(x)/ln(y).$

Comment: $a_n=ln\big(\frac{n+1}{n}\big)$, not $\frac{ln(n+1)}{ln\,n}$

Comment: $A - B \ne \frac AB$ so $\ln (n+1) - \ln n \ne \frac {\ln (n+1)}{\ln n}$.  You are confusing the rule of $\ln (A) - \ln (B) = \ln (\frac AB)$.  So $\ln (n+1) - \ln (n) = \ln (\frac {n+1}{n})=\ln(1 + \frac 1n)$.  So$ \lim (ln (n+1) - \ln n) = \lim (1 + \frac 1n) = \ln 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not true that
$$\ln(n+1) - \ln(n) = \frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}$$

Instead,

$$\ln(n+1)-\ln(n) = \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

This is 
$$
\int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} dx
$$
and therefore between $0$ and $\frac{1}{n}$. Another way to see that the limit is 0.